# Many down votes without explanation

Tags: support, down-votes

From yesterday I was seeing there are many down votes are being given to the questions, without explanation. Today I found this question 
[can-code-completion-be-consideration-of-choosing-a-programming-language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181332/can-code-completion-be-consideration-of-choosing-a-programming-language)
which I think is a good fit, but again given down vote and no-one in the comments has mentioned about down vote. 
Also one of the answer for some other question has unexplained down vote. [unnecessary down vote](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/181331/8820).
I could have given up votes but I do not want to give up vote just to avoid down votes. Isn't there any way to avoid this **anonymous down voting?**.

Comment: related discussion at MSO: **[Encouraging people to explain down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/165773)**

Answer (score 7):

Down voting is anonymous by design and will always remain so. Down-voters are free to down-vote anything they want for any reasons. The most common reasons being poor quality or an incorrect answer/assumption. In both cases you point out there are big quality issues. The first questions is incoherent and borderline not a real question. The answer you link to is a poor quality answer, it doesn't really answer the question (which is also bad) and would qualify as a link only answer if it had a link.